# What would life be like that uses liquid nitrogen as a solvent instead of water?

Tags: planets, creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry

I'm working on a worldbuilding project and want to have an intelligent species from a planet where liquid nitrogen is the dominant solvent, not water. I plan on building the planet backwards from here so they could exist with any sort of atmosphere or pressure? What would the life forms that evolved here be like? What kind of biochemistry could they have? Cheers!

Comment: What they would be like is likely asking too much from us, look at our fresh water-based life, there are all kinds of animals and plants. I highly doubt liquid nitrogen ones will restrict much the variety, even if we forbid ourselves to stray away from most likely real-world models and simulations :| .

Comment: Greetings shesahuman! To follow on what Tortliena said, in this forum, we're looking for fairly *focused* queries that ask about a specific worldbuilding problem or issue you're trying to solve. Any question that would literally take a book to answer in neither focused nor specific. A question like this really needs to be broken up into multiple different questions focused on different parts of the bigger problem. You might consider tackling this by deleting this question and placing it in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)

Comment: Hello @shesahuman, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. I apologize, but I'm compelled to vote to close your question. As written, your question violates a great many of both Stack Exchange's rules and this Stack's rules. You are allowed to ask one and only one specific and focused question that can be reasonably answered with a page of text. You've asked us to invent and entire planetary ecology. Please carefully read our [tour] and the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. Thanks.

Comment: The critical point of nitrogen is at 126.2 K (−147 °C) and 33 atmospheres. Liquid nitrogen cannot exist at a temperature above −147 °C (−232 °F). That's *cold*, very very cold. Chemical reactions happen very very slowly, if at all, at such low tempeatures. Whatever life may exist in such cryogenic conditions, one thing is for sure: it will move at a glacial pace.

Comment: Liquid nitrogen is a pretty poor solvent. It lacks a lot of the interesting chemical and physical properties that water has, so it probably couldn't become the basis for a biochemistry. Perhaps rewrite/rethink to use some other chemical?